# Calling mulltiple methods of the same class

Tags: php, methods

In my class `Helper()` I have 2 methods which look like this:

```
public function is_active_page($page) {
    $url = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    if (end($url) === $page) {
        return true;
    }
}

public function go_to_dashboard() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('Location: http://example.com');
    }
}
```

I would now like to call them like this: `$helper->is_active_page('page')->go_to_dashboard();` instead of using 2 lines for each method.

For some reason this is not working for me. Why?

Comment: that's wrong idea, `is_active_page()` method should return `boolean` result according to its semantics

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to chain methods, those methods need to return the original Helper instance. Try returning `$this` from inside the methods. Like RomanPerekhrest commented however, I dont think the methods you listed here are suitable for chaining. You would be better off with adding another method to your class that combines the two you stated here.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but something along the lines of below might be what you are looking for:

```
public function redirect($page){
    if($this->is_active_page($page)){
        $this->go_to_dashboard();
    }
}
```

Lastly, you could think about reducing the scope of your `is_active_page` and `go_to_dashboard` functions, if they no longer need to be called from outside the `Helper` class.